# pandas add rows to original df based on groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to group by text, if at least one name exists, then loop through the names, and each name that does not appear - add a line to original df.
example -

```
names_set = {'A','B','C'}
```

initial df:

```
columns = ['id','text','name','start','end']
data = [
    [1,"this is text 1", 'A',0,4],
    [2,"this is text 1", 'B',4,5],
    [3,"this is text 1", 'C',4,5],
    [3,"this is text 2", 'A',6,8],
    [4,'this is text 3',None, None, None],
    [5,"this is text 4", 'B',10,13],
    [6,"this is text 4", 'B',1,5]
]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data= data,columns=columns)
df1

    id  text           name     start   end
0   1   this is text 1  A       0.0     4.0
1   2   this is text 1  B       4.0     5.0
2   3   this is text 1  C       4.0     5.0
3   3   this is text 2  A       6.0     8.0
4   4   this is text 3  None    NaN     NaN
5   5   this is text 4  B       10.0    13.0
6   6   this is text 4  B       1.0     5.0
```

output:

```
columns2 = ['id','text','name','start','end']
data2 = [
    [1,"this is text 1", 'A',0,4],
    [2,"this is text 1", 'B',4,5],
    [3,"this is text 1", 'C',4,5],
    [3,"this is text 2", 'A',6,8],
    [None,"this is text 2", 'B',None,None],
    [None,"this is text 2", 'C',None,None],
    [4,'this is text 3',None, None, None],
    [None,"this is text 4", 'A',None,None],
    [5,"this is text 4", 'B',10,13],
    [6,"this is text 4", 'B',1,5],
    [None,"this is text 4", 'C',None,None]
]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data= data2,columns=columns2)
df2
    id  text            name    start   end
0   1.0 this is text 1  A       0.0     4.0
1   2.0 this is text 1  B       4.0     5.0
2   3.0 this is text 1  C       4.0     5.0
3   3.0 this is text 2  A       6.0     8.0
4   NaN this is text 2  B       NaN     NaN
5   NaN this is text 2  C       NaN     NaN
6   4.0 this is text 3  None    NaN     NaN
7   NaN this is text 4  A       NaN     NaN
8   5.0 this is text 4  B       10.0    13.0
9   6.0 this is text 4  B       1.0     5.0
10  NaN this is text 4  C       NaN     NaN
```

the code I have up until now -

```
g = df1.groupby('text')
text_names_group = df1.groupby("text")["name"].agg(list)
text_names_group
for text in text_names_group:
  if len(text) == 1 and text[0] is None:
    continue
  cur_names = set(text)
  missing_names_per_text = names_set - cur_names
```

so missing_names_per_text is what the names missing for each text, but I want to add it to the original df, per text

Thanks!

## edit : there's an option for two lines with same text and name, but different start and end

example - added line 6 in input

Comment: `df2 = df1.set_index(['text', 'name']).reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1['text'].unique(), names_set], names=['text', 'name'])).reset_index()[df1.columns]`

Comment: @mozway - No, it is only part of solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter only rows match by `names_set` and add missing combinations, last append not matching rows by invert mask by `~` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
names_set = {'A','B','C'} 

m = df1['name'].isin(names_set)
df2 = (df1.set_index(['text', 'name'])
            .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.loc[m, 'text'].unique(), 
                                                 sorted(names_set)], 
                                                names=['text', 'name']))).reset_index()

df = pd.concat([df1[~m], df2]).sort_values(['text'], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
    id            text  name  start   end
0  1.0  this is text 1     A    0.0   4.0
1  2.0  this is text 1     B    4.0   5.0
2  3.0  this is text 1     C    4.0   5.0
3  3.0  this is text 2     A    6.0   8.0
4  NaN  this is text 2     B    NaN   NaN
5  NaN  this is text 2     C    NaN   NaN
6  4.0  this is text 3  None    NaN   NaN
7  NaN  this is text 4     A    NaN   NaN
8  5.0  this is text 4     B   10.0  13.0
9  NaN  this is text 4     C    NaN   NaN
```

In ral data should be problem sorting by `text` column, so here is solution with mapping by `enumerate` dictionary:

```
columns = ['id','text','name','start','end']
data = [
    [1,"this is text 10", 'A',0,4],
    [2,"this is text 10", 'B',4,5],
    [3,"this is text 10", 'C',4,5],
    [3,"this is text 20", 'A',6,8],
    [4,'this is text 13',None, None, None],
    [5,"this is text 14", 'B',10,13]
]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data= data,columns=columns)
```

---

```
names_set = {'A','B','C'} 


m = df1['name'].isin(names_set)

sorting = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(df1['text'].drop_duplicates())}
print (sorting)
{'this is text 10': 0, 'this is text 20': 1, 'this is text 13': 2, 'this is text 14': 3}

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.loc[m, 'text'].unique(), 
                                 sorted(names_set)], 
                                 names=['text', 'name'])

df2 = df1.set_index(['text', 'name']).reindex(mux).reset_index()

df = pd.concat([df1[~m], df2]).sort_values(['text'], 
                                           ignore_index=True, 
                                           key=lambda x: x.map(sorting))
print (df2)
              text name   id  start   end
0  this is text 10    A  1.0    0.0   4.0
1  this is text 10    B  2.0    4.0   5.0
2  this is text 10    C  3.0    4.0   5.0
3  this is text 20    A  3.0    6.0   8.0
4  this is text 20    B  NaN    NaN   NaN
5  this is text 20    C  NaN    NaN   NaN
6  this is text 14    A  NaN    NaN   NaN
7  this is text 14    B  5.0   10.0  13.0
8  this is text 14    C  NaN    NaN   NaN
```

Solution with duplicated `name`s per groups is similar:

```
names_set = {'A','B','C'} 

m = df1['name'].isin(names_set)

sorting = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(df1['text'].drop_duplicates())}
#print (sorting)
```

Create helper `df3` DataFrame by [`MultiIndex.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html), add missing `text` and `name` rows and last use left join with original DataFrame:

```
df3 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.loc[m, 'text'].unique(), 
                                 sorted(names_set)], 
                                 names=['text', 'name']).to_frame(index=False)

df3 = (pd.concat([df1.loc[~m, ['text', 'name']], df3])
         .sort_values(['text'], ignore_index=True, key=lambda x: x.map(sorting)))
print (df3)
      text  name
0  this is text 1     A
1  this is text 1     B
2  this is text 1     C
3  this is text 2     A
4  this is text 2     B
5  this is text 2     C
6  this is text 3  None
7  this is text 4     A
8  this is text 4     B
9  this is text 4     C
```

---

```
df2 = df3.merge(df1, how='left')
print (df2)
              text  name   id  start   end
0   this is text 1     A  1.0    0.0   4.0
1   this is text 1     B  2.0    4.0   5.0
2   this is text 1     C  3.0    4.0   5.0
3   this is text 2     A  3.0    6.0   8.0
4   this is text 2     B  NaN    NaN   NaN
5   this is text 2     C  NaN    NaN   NaN
6   this is text 3  None  4.0    NaN   NaN
7   this is text 4     A  NaN    NaN   NaN
8   this is text 4     B  5.0   10.0  13.0
9   this is text 4     B  6.0    1.0   5.0
10  this is text 4     C  NaN    NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you! when I ran on my data I've notice I forgot to add that there can be a text tagged by the same name twice, so `df2 = df1.set_index(['text', 'annotation.annotator']).reindex(mux).reset_index()` throws `ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!` I've edited my question